# How to access the actual file from the filepond component in React?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, peerjs, filepond

I have a React website built with vite and I am trying to send file from a peer to another via peerjs. I was doing this manually at first by storing the files in a state variable and sending them to the other peer via a custom function when the user clicks a button.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
```

```
const handleDataTransfer = (content) => {
    if (content.type === "file") {
        conn.send({
            type: "file",
            data: {
                file: content.data,
                filename: content.data.name,
                filetype: content.data.type,
            },
        });
    }
};

onClick={() => {
    handleDataTransfer({ type: "file", data: file });
}}
```

Currenlty I am trying to implement a drag and drop interface for the file transfer using [React FilePond](https://npmjs.com/package/react-filepond) but I'm not sure:

1. how to get the actual file uploaded by the user from the FilePond component or the `files` state.
2. what to pass to `load()` (see [process](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process-1)) as there is no file id and I don't plan on having a restore function

Here in my FilePond component:

```
<FilePond
  allowRemove={true}
  instantUpload={false}
  allowRevert={false}
  allowImagePreview={true}
  imagePreviewHeight={60}
  files={files}
  onupdatefiles={setFiles}
  allowMultiple={true}
  maxFiles={10}

  server={{
    process: (
      fieldName,
      file,
      metadata,
      load,
      error,
      progress,
      abort,
      transfer,
      options
    ) => {
      handleDataTransfer(/* the uploaded files here */);

      // can't measure transfer progress in peerjs transfers
      progress(false, 0, 100);
      load("1234");
    },
  }}

  name="files" /* sets the file input name, it's filepond by default */
  labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
/>;
```